# How to determine in Visual Studio that the current caret position is in a comment block?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++

Is there a way to determine programmatically in a Visual Studio code editor ( C/C++ or C# ) that the current caret position is within a comment block ( after "//" or between /* */ )? I tried to use IContentType like this:

```
if ( m_textView.TextBuffer.ContentType.TypeName == "comment" )
```

but it seems that ContentType.BaseTypes contain only more general content types (like "text", "code", "C/C++") relating to the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`IClassifierAggregatorService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.classification.iclassifieraggregatorservice.aspx) to access the classifications used for syntax highlighting in the editor. If you don't beat me to it, I'll post a more complete example this evening showing the extraction of the `IClassificationType` of the text under the caret.

Answer (score 1):

The `ContentType` property refers to the content of the `ITextBuffer` instance.  This is typically C#, text, code, etc ...  It doesn't hold semantic information like comment or keyword

Unfortunately there is currently no good API that exposes this information.  Comments are a language specific construct and the only general purpose language API in Visual Studio at the moment is the Code Model and I don't believe it supports comments.

In the future APIs like Roslyn will provide the information you are looking for.  This won't be available until at least the release after Visual Studio 2013

**EDIT**

There's been some speculation as to whether or not `IClassificationType` could be used to get information about comments.  At a high level this could indeed be used although it is probably something I would avoid doing.  I've been bitten in the past several times trying to grab information from classifiers on demand.  There are a lot of subtle perf issues you can run into.

Comment: @JaredPar - Thanks for the answer. I thought that as soon as the comments are properly highlighted by the language service package, it's somehow possible to obtain the needed information from some of language service interfaces (IVsProvideColorableItems or something).

Comment: @280Z28 - I found an interface looking relevant to the question, but still can't figure out how to use it: IStandardClassificationService

Comment: @280Z28 - Thank you. With this class and calls to GetClassifier() and then GetClassificationSpans() one gets the span type "comment" when the caret is in a comment block.