# Determine if the caret is in a comment block with Visual Studio SDK

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

### Scenario

---

I would like to enable a command in a custom menu only if the caret is in a Xml comment block

```
''' ... If caret is here, in a Vb.Net Xml comment block.
```

or

```
/// ... If caret is here, in a C# Xml comment block.
```

Then, a pseudo-code of the expecting results:

C#:

```
private void CmdExample_BeforeQueryStatus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Enable this command only if the caret is in a Xml comment block.
    ((OleMenuCommand)sender).Enabled = IsCaretInXmlComment?();
}
```

Vb:

```
Private Sub CmdExample_BeforeQueryStatus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles cmdExample.BeforeQueryStatus

    ' Enable this command only if the caret is in a Xml comment block.
    DirectCast(sender, OleMenuCommand).Enabled = IsCaretInXmlComment?()

End Sub
```

### Question

---

Just, how I could do it?. In Vb.Net or C#.

### Research

---

I'm not sure how to do this, so I was in a trial-and-error with the values of the `vsCMElement` enum because I seen something similar **[here](http://www.helixoft.com/blog/collapse-all-xml-comments-in-vb-net-or-c.html)**, but the `CodeElement2.Kind` property always throw a `NullReferenceException`.

C#:

```
TextPoint tp = 
    ((TextSelection)MyDte.ActiveDocument.Selection).ActivePoint;

CodeElement2 ce = 
    MyDte.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.
          CodeElementFromPoint(tp, vsCMElement.vsCMElementOther);
```

Vb:

```
Dim tp As TextPoint = 
    CType(MyDte.ActiveDocument.Selection, TextSelection).ActivePoint

Dim ce As CodeElement2 =
    MyDte.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.
          CodeElementFromPoint(tp, vsCMElement.vsCMElementOther)
```

I also found this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616756/how-to-determine-in-visual-studio-that-the-current-caret-position-is-in-a-commen)**, however without an illustrative code-example I'm very lost about this.

Comment: Two questions that guide the answer: which language do  you want to do the detection in? i.e. what types of files, if open, matter? Also, what is your minimum version of Visual Studio you need to target?

Comment: @Jason Malinowski Thanks for comment. I'm developing the extension in Vb.Net, here is the installer: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/776ff18b-d8a8-43cc-82c1-a65a8509202b and here the source-code: http://www.mediafire.com/download/kih2744ii5il1rf/Snippet+Tool+Extension.rar , however I could translate a C# sample. The extension should work for both Vb and C# comment-blocks detection. What types of files?: Vb and C# source files of course, and only for the active document in the current code editor window (not all open documents). I'm targeting Visual Studio 2013 SDK.

Comment: Detecting the active document and its language is a thing that I solved in the past, I only need help to determine if the caret position is in a XML comment block of type VB.Net or C#, the type of active document file really doesn't matter, I preffer to do any filter about that, because a text file (.txt) for whatever reason could contains a code-sample of VB or C# with xml comments too.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm in search of a more consistent approach than getting the line from caret position, trim the line, then detect whether the first three chars are "'''" or "///". I would like to detect if the block is a fully-qualified Xml comment-block (this means, with a starting and ending xml tag)

Comment: The minimum version you still want to target is 2012? This is easier with 2015 now that Roslyn is there, but that would kill compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting Visual Studio 2015 or higher, the best way to do this is with Roslyn. With it you can get a syntax tree and then figure out if you're in a comment. If you look at our implementation of [IsEntirelyWithinSingleLineDocComment](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/Extensions/SyntaxTreeExtensions.cs,262) you can see how we do it today. There are already existing questions out there to help you get a syntax tree if you're new to Roslyn.

If you're needing to target versions lower than that, then you're in trouble since Roslyn first shipped in 2012. One common approach is to instead ask for classification information to figure out if something is a comment or not. Classifications are what drives the text coloring you see in the editor. If you get an `ITextBuffer` for your file, then you can MEF import `IClassifierAggregatorService` and ask for classifications, and then filter to the doc comment types. [Noah Richard's original spell check sample](https://github.com/NoahRic/Spellchecker/blob/master/SpellChecker.Implementation/NaturalTextTaggers/CommentTextTagger.cs#L83) is a good example of how to do this.

Comment: If you're targeting VS before Roslyn, or are interested in an alternative technology, you can use NRefactory: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code